# how do i know when I can divide by the highest denominator power?

Tags: calculus

When there are radicals in limits I understand you have to either first

1. Divide by highest denominator power
2. multiply by conjugate

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{x^2+5x}-x\right)$ **solved by multiplying by conjugate**

$\lim _{t\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\sqrt{t}+t^2}{6t-t^2}\right)$ **solved by dividing by highest denominator power**

Is it because one has the x in both numerator and denominator?

I want to be extra clear on that so I don't do the mistake I have done in the past where I did this...

$\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\left(\sqrt{x^2+5x}-x\right)\:$

$=\:\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{5x}{x^2}}-\frac{x}{x}\right)\:$

$=\:\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x}}-1\right)\:$

$=\:\sqrt{1+0}-1\:=\:0$

And I was certain I did good :c

Edit as im writed this I realized that since is not in a fraction im changing the result by dividing? but what about this?

$=\:\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:\infty \:\:}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{5x}{x^2}}-\frac{x}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}\right)\:$

Comment: As for your edit, you multiplied top and bottom by 1/x, which is okay, but how does that help evaluate the limit? Given the square root, it makes sense to multiply top and bottom by conjugate in that example.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio btw sorry for my English. I don't know If I'm making my self clear. This is what I'm trying to figure out, when to use what method

Comment: ok, see my updated response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods for evaluating limits, two of which you mention. Keep in mind you must multiply (or divide) *both* numerator and denominator by the same thing to preserve the same expression. In your (incorrect) example, you simply divided the whole thing through by $x$, which changes the expression.

---

Here's the quick and dirty for the kinds of examples you mention, where you know one of those two approaches will work and are just trying to decide which one to use in evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)$:

If plugging in $x=\infty$ into the expression gives $\infty-\infty$, then evaluate the limit by multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate.

If plugging in $x=\infty$ into the expression gives $\pm \infty/\infty$, then evaluate the limit by dividing top and bottom by the highest degree term.

---

However, I would like to point out there is no one good way to evaluate limits. Rather than memorize rules, just try different approaches; if one approach doesn't help you evaluate a limit, try another (as long as you don't change the original expression as you did in your example!)

Comment: I realized that and was editing it xd but what about my new edit? why that wont work?

Comment: @centenond see my comment to your post

Comment: @centenond make sense now?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Wouldn't have guessed that.

Comment: this is only with limits tends to ∞ right? if it tends to a number you would just multiply by the conjugate ?

Comment: @centenond Sorry, could you give me an example of what you had in mind. An expression may still tend to infinity even if x tends to a finite number. There is no single good method to evaluate a limit, so it's much easier to discuss methods with particular examples.

Comment: well i mean if you plug in x to $\lim _{x\to 9}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{x-9}\right)$ by sustitucion you get 0/0. The trick doesn't work here cuz if you plugin you won't get either ∞-∞ or ∞/∞. So i was asking if this trick is only when $x\to \pm \infty \:$

Comment: I guess the example I made above is obvious you should multiply conjugate because the indetermination is already in the denominator, and we need it to cancel that. But you get the point

Comment: @centenond Right, you could technically write it as a "$\infty/\infty$" kind of limit by writing it as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 9} \frac{1/(x-9)}{1/(\sqrt{x}-3)}.$ Writing it as such doesn't necessarily help evaluate it though; as you point out, you can evaluate the limit in this case by simply multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{x}+3.$

Comment: Here's another example where $x$ doesn't approach $\infty$: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sqrt{1/x^4+5/x^2}-1/x^2.$ This has the form $\infty-\infty$ and multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate of the whole expression allows you to find the limit (which is $5/2$). So the rules can still be applied in this case.

Comment: But honestly, it would make more sense to get practice with different examples and use your judgement rather than try to remember "rules" set in stone, as there is no one good way to evaluate limits. You can always try one approach, and if it doesn't get you anywhere, try another (as long as you don't change the original expression!). In calculus, you will likely encounter L'Hopital's rule and infinite series, which give powerful methods to tackle many kinds of limits in general.